# How could Armored Gorilla beat Marshall Gorilla?

Tags: one-punch-man

https://onepunchman.fandom.com/wiki/Armored_Gorilla

[image]

We all remember this gorilla in season 1, who seems really weak and **lost against Genos**.

---

In season 2, we see him beating Marshall Gorilla in one punch.

[image]

---

It sounded very weird to me. The previous episodes showed the monsters of Orochi very strong, and need S-Class Heroes to beat them.

Marshall Gorilla is the same kind as the **Supersado girl**. 
But Fubuki needed Tatsumaki help to beat her.

[image]

---

**He was followed by Zombieman, an S-Class Hero, who was worried about that Marshall Gorilla, so it means that he's as strong as a S-Class Hero...**

**So if this Gorilla is so strong, how can that weak Armored Gorilla beat him?**

Comment: Reason of negative vote?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Armored Gorilla looked very weak despite claiming to be extremely strong. This is because he was very quickly and easily beaten by Genos.  Also, Genos looks weak compared to the other human there... Saitama.

However, Genos soon after became an S class hero and clearly deserves that ranking based on his skill level.  So Genos is S class level.  Genos and Saitama are absurdly strong and are ridiculous standards to compare to.

You argue that Marshall Gorilla needed someone on the level of an S class hero to beat them.  I would argue that they need an A class hero or similar to beat them but that doesn't matter.  This episode establishes that Marshall Gorilla should be strong enough to at least defeat most A class heroes.

His easy defeat just shows that Armored Gorilla actually was very strong... he looked weak only because of how amazingly strong Genos and (by extension) Saitama are.

Retrospectively, we should know that he was that strong as Genos's defeat of that laboratory alone was enough to skyrocket him up to S rank immediately. While you may want to attribute that strength to Saitama as Saitama beat Kabuto, the hero association was probably not aware of Kabuto so did not include him in their calculations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think you're right, they are A-level monsters after all. I take your answer

Answer (score 3):

### **Armored Gorilla is stronger than Marshal Gorilla**

If we are going to base on threat level alone, *Armored Gorilla is Demon level* while *Marshall Gorilla is Tiger level*

[image: Armored Gorilla vs Marshall Gorilla]

But of course we can't just use the threat level alone.

---

So let's look how the battle goes on between the two:

> Marshall Gorilla uses his Banana Slash to Armored Gorilla, the same technique he use to defeat the A-rank hero Heavy Kong. The attack didn't even budged Armored Gorilla and the knife was broken, from this we can completely see the power difference between the two and we can say the Armored Gorilla is really stronger that Marshall Gorilla.
>  [image: Marshall Gorilla uses his Banana Slash] 
>  [image]

---

*Zombieman is not worried about Marshall Gorilla*, he is following him for a different reason:

> Zombieman want to know their location that's why he is following him
>  [image: Zombieman reason for following Marshall Gorilla1]
>  [image: Zombieman reason for following Marshall Gorilla2]

Comment: Thanks for answering. I accept your argument of Monster Level. But I don't agree with that As i explained, Marshall Gorilla is same kind than Supersado girl. And to beat Supersado, they needed Tatsumaki (S-Class Hero).  But Armored Gorilla is weak, as we saw on Season 1 Episode 2, Genos (who was weak at this time, comparing to now) beat him easily. So these titles mean nothing
And I remember on the Anime, I saw Zombieman with a panic face

Comment: That categorization by the hero association it is probably as wrong as when they say King is an S class hero

Answer (score 1):

It's all about match ups. Nothing to do with power. Although power can make a huge difference if they are as strong as tatsumaki. But you have to realize that fubuki and her gang doesn't even match up to most heroes on A levels. Fubuki although being B class could be considered A since she is top 1 and could do well. Genos is also a pretty strong character but his main role is to make saitama look stronger by making him lose to the enemies that saitama could beat. He didn't get S by just being a tactician. His physical levels are off the charts. Remember deep sea King? He took out 2 S class heroes and made sonic retreat but he is only a demon level threat. Same level with armored gorilla. But like I said, it's all about match ups too. Deep sea King is physically strong and even stronger and faster in the rain. Some heroes could be advantageous against certain monsters. Like VS Boros. I'm pretty sure most of the S class heroes won't hold up to him unless they teamed up. The only one I think would have a chance would be tatsumaki.